# Processing files. What's wrong?

Tags: perl

I have this code which skips lines that start with `#`

```
while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {

    if ($line =~ /^#/) { next; }

    $line =~ /^(\w+);(\w+);.*$/;
    $user_map{$2} = $1;
}
```

and I would think that this code did the same

```
while (defined (my $line = <FILE>)) {

    unless ($line =~ /^#/) {
    $line =~ /^(\w+);(\w+);.*$/;
    $user_map{$2} = $1;
    }

}
```

but it doesn't.

What's wrong with the last code?

**Update:** Replaced `# do stuff` with actual code.

Comment: Comment in detail what happens and how both versions differ. As far as *I* can see the code should actually do the same.

Comment: I don't see anything that should cause a difference either. How are you seeing them behave differently? Can you provide an example of input for which you're getting different results?

Comment: the ".*$" part of your pattern does not do anything useful, so it should not be there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both blocks of code should behave identically. Check if there are any typos.

Comment: You are right. They actually do the same. I have no idea why they didn't do that before.